# Mysql - Call a procedure from procedure but get FUNCTION does not exist

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I got "FUNCTION does not exist" when I tried to call a procedure from procedure.

Here is how I call:

```
CALL GET_ACTIVITY_PERIOD(start_time, act_start, act_end, hours);
```

GET_PERIOD procedure is created successfully and looks like:

> "CREATE PROCEDURE GET_ACTIVITY_PERIOD(IN sale_time DATETIME, OUT
>   bracket_starttime VARCHAR(5), OUT bracket_endtime VARCHAR(5), OUT
>   hours INT) .... "

Please tell me if I missed anything.
Any help is appreciated.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you had created the stored procedure in same database in which you are calling it.
or mention database name while calling it.
Like

CALL SANDB.GET_ACTIVITY_PERIOD(start_time, act_start, act_end, hours);

Comment: Yes, it is in the same database. I run "show procedure status;" and see all of procedures are in the correct database. Beside, the error shows "FUNCTION Xstore.GET_ACTIVITY_PERIOD does not exist". Xstore is exactly the databseI am using.

Comment: Can you paste entire stored procedure, would like to see how OUT parameters are working

Comment: CREATE PROCEDURE GET_ACTIVITY_PERIOD(IN sale_time DATETIME, OUT bracket_starttime VARCHAR(5), OUT bracket_endtime VARCHAR(5), OUT hours INT) 
BEGIN
DECLARE minutes INT;
  SET hours = DATE_FORMAT(sale_time, '%H');
  SET minutes = DATE_FORMAT(sale_time, '%i');
  IF minutes < '15' THEN
    SET bracket_starttime = '00';
    SET bracket_endtime   = '14';
    SET hours = (hours * 60) / 15;
  ELSE
    SET bracket_starttime = '45';
    SET bracket_endtime   = '59';
    SET hours = (hours * 60) / 15 + 3;
  END IF;
END;

Comment: sorry, it is not well formatted when I paste the procedure here

Comment: Try calling like: 
call GET_ACTIVITY_PERIOD('2015-10-05 11:15:38', '@'act_start, '@'act_end, '@'hours);
remove (') before and after '@' in call statement

Comment: I tried and get the same error when I run the caller procedure. However, I am able to run only the call procedure line in tools like SQLDeveloper or HeidiSQL. It returns the correct OUT parameter value.

Comment: would like to know your calling procedure, can you paste it.

Comment: it's very long. so I remove the parts no related to the Call: DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS SAVE_SALES;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE SAVE_SALES(store_id VARCHAR(5),
..
   is_void BIGINT)
-- define period variable for productivity tables
DECLARE activity_prd   INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE activity_start VARCHAR(5);
DECLARE activity_end   VARCHAR(5);
..
  -- update to columns in workstation productivity
  CALL GET_ACTIVITY_PERIOD('2015-09-24 11:37:44', '@'act_start, '@'act_end, '@'hours);
  SET activity_start = @act_start;
  SET activity_end = @act_end;
  SET activity_prd = @hours;
...
END; $$
DELIMITER ;

Comment: I have used the following procedure based on yours _DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE SAVE_SALES() -- define period variable for productivity tables 
BEGIN
DECLARE hours INT DEFAULT 0; 
DECLARE act_start VARCHAR(5); 
DECLARE act_end VARCHAR(5);

CALL GET_ACTIVITY_PERIOD('2015-09-24 11:37:44', '@'act_start, '@'act_end, '@'hours);
END//

DELIMITER ;_ and after I CALL SAVE_SALES(); I get no error & act_start = 45, act_end = 59 and hours = 47 as expected. (GET_ACTIVITY_PERIOD created with your original code)

Comment: If I drop the GET_ACTIVITY_PERIOD stored procedure I get this error _Error Code: 1305. PROCEDURE test.GET_ACTIVITY_PERIOD does not exist_

Comment: Try using MySQL workbench, it will give you good boost to start with mysql.

Comment: I try the procedure from @PaulF and it also works for me. I think there is something wrong in my caller procedure. I just don't understand that why it keep saying "Function does not exist" when I use "Call" to call a procedure. Is there anything else could be a reason it recognized my call as a function?

Comment: The only way I get the Function does not exist error is to use an assign _SET @Res = GET_ACTIVITY_PERIOD(....._

Comment: ok. it must be something wrong in my caller procedure. I will check it again. Thank you @PaulF and Gaurav Lad for your support.